# How to maintain login session across multiple tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, session

I am developing a website and i am having a problem in finding the best solution to maintain user login session.
Currently i am using Html5 web storage "session storage" to store whether user is logged in or not. But problem in this is that this only works in a single tab not across multiple tabs of a browser.

What should i use either Cookies or LocalStorage or i should maintain server side session and check every times a page loads on server whether the user is logged in or not ?

What is the best solution? please guide me.
I am using Node.js and mongodb in the backend and Angular and jquery in frontend.

Comment: client side session for login, sound really unsecure. Server side is the best solution, combined with localstorage (so it will work across tabs)

Comment: i agree with you but what troubles me in applying server side session is that everytime a page loads a request goes to server about whether user is logged in or not and this sounds to me time consuming in page loading and for local storage if user forgots to logout, the user will be logged in everytime.
By the way how to use server side combined with localstorage. ?
you mean like when user log in, i should store a variable in local storage that says that this user is logged in

Comment: normally you should not care about checking if user is logined or not, session will do that, you should just have a upper level module/class or request interceptor that checks every time if current session is authorized. This as php session. The only difference in your case is that you should syncronize this session with a token since you're using js app

Comment: Can you explain me little bit how it works? or may be send me some link from where i can refer or can get to know how to implement what you said

Comment: @albanx please elaborate.

Comment: @SteveC nothing special to elaborate: user logins making request to server. open new tab, send a rest/ajax request to server to check if user is login. that's it. localstorage can be used to store the current status but is not mandatory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you must know is that sessions are made only for server-side not for client side. Second thing, if you want your user to not load everytime, try to save the data in user's cookies also don't think about it will require more time to load on server. Because sessions are only made for security purpose and i guess by storing them on client side you are not using that purpose. Also now major question is how to store them on the server side. Suppose your server goes down now all of your sessions will get deleted. Now to avoid that use some external data store like connect-mongo/connect-redis. redis is faster than mongo but if you want to use only memory store then search for memcached/cookie-sessions/jWT hope this answer helps :)